# View controller Specifc routes on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I view controller specific routes in rails.I've large number of controller in my project. So I want to view routes for specific controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
rake routes CONTROLLER=controller_name
```

ex: `rake routes CONTROLLER=posts`